# mvc data annotation to restrict user to not allow only numeric numbers and special characters

Tags: regex, asp.net-mvc-4, data-annotations

i am trying to validate the input of a user to insert only alphanumeric characters including special characters like .,_ white space.

```
Point 1. the user cant insert only special characters like @@@@@@@ or .........
Point 2. or any numeric numbers like 2222222.
```

it should be any valid format like. `"hi i am asking a question on stack overflow.this is my 11th attempt.  "`

i tried these expressions but its not let me restrict user like point 1 and pont 2 ,please help.

here is my code

```
[RegularExpression(@"^([a-zA-Z0-9 \.\&\'\-]+)$", ErrorMessage = "Invalid User Name")]
        public string UserName { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [StringLength(250, MinimumLength = 5, ErrorMessage = "User Description must have minimum 5 and maximum 250 characters.")]
        [RegularExpression(@"^[^<>!@#%/?*]+$", ErrorMessage = "Invalid User Description")]
        public string Description { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use a negative lookahead at the start.

```
@"^(?![\W_]+$)(?!\d+$)[a-zA-Z0-9 .&',_-]+$"
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/wY6nI2/3)

- `(?![\W_]+$)` Negative lookahead asserts that the string won't contain  only  special characters.
- `(?!\d+$)` asserts that the string won't contain  only digits.

Comment: Thank you for your answer its fine . but it not allowing me the comma and underscore, can you sort out this.

Comment: you could reduce the above regex to `@"^(?![\W_]+$)(?!\d+$)[\w .&',-]+$"`

Answer (score 0):

```
^(?=.*[a-zA-Z])[a-zA-Z0-9,_.&' -]+$
```

You can enforce a condition thru `lookahead` stating that a `letter` is always necessary.